# Paypal Sandbox Subscriptions PAYER_CANNOT_PAY

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm using the Paypal Sandbox environment, and using `createSubscription(data, actions)` in the Javascript SDK.

When testing, the popup appears correctly but when I go through with the payment it always returns the error:

`PAYER_CANNOT_PAY`

Logging into the sandbox buyer account, the subscription IS created, but the subscription payment is not taken.  If I add a setup fee, this fee is successfully charged but again the subscription payment is not taken.

I'm at a complete loss as to what the issue could be if anyone knows!

Comment: Likely just a problem with subscriptions in the sandbox environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the stupid error, was calling the `onApprove` method for the non-subscription method